# wordpress cntactform7 email not submit

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

In [wordpress](http://wordpress.org/) I am using [contactform7](http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) plugin for contact form. In that my required fields for forms are below.

```
<h3>Personal Details </h3>
<p>Title:[checkbox*  title class:title exclusive "Mr." "Dr." "Mrs." "Miss." "Ms." "Other"]</p>
<p>First Name: [text* first-name class:first-name]</p>
<p>Middle Name: [text middle-name class:middle-name]</p>
<p>Last Name:[text* last-name class:last-name]</p>
<p>Disability:[checkbox disability exclusive "No" "Yes" ] <br />
If yes, please specify [text Disability-name ]</p>
<p>E-Mail Address: [email* email-address class:email-address]</p>
<p>Telephone (Day): [text telephone-day ]</p>
 Please use the following links to attach further documents to support your application.
[file* file-590 class:file-upload limit:5mb filetypes:pdf|doc]
[submit class:submit]
```

Now after all the fields filled when I am clicking on submit button it is showing error in firefox console tab like and the email is not doing submit

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
{"mailSent":false,"into":"#wpcf7-f2472-t1-o1","captcha":null,"message":
```

So can someone kindly tell me what's the wrong here? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: You're missing a semi-colon. (although, not in the provided code)

Comment: @ahren thanks for the reply but where is the missing semi-colon?

Comment: It's not in the code you've provided above.